# I want to delete last element from ptree type data of boost library

Tags: c++11, boost

I have data in JSON format and I want to delete last data that data in the following format:

```
"data":
  {
    "user":
     {
      "addr":[

       [
         {
          "firstline":"123",
          "secondline":"LA"

        },
          {
          "firstline":"643",
          "secondline":"NY"
          },
          {
          "firstline":" ",
          "secondline":"VA"
           }

         ]
      ]
   }
}
```

I want to delete the last address of the above user which contains empty firstline.

Comment: Please show us what you have done till now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With an enormous caveat, that Boost Proprty Tree is NOT a JSON library. There are many things it cannot properly represent.
>
> You will probably run into this because your sample is not even valid JSON to begin with

So, let's read the fixed up data into a property tree:

```
std::istringstream iss(R"({"data": {
"user": {
    "addr": [ [ 
        { "firstline": "123", "secondline": "LA" },
        { "firstline": "643", "secondline": "NY" },
        { "firstline": " ", "secondline": "VA" }
    ] ]
}
```

}})");

```
boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
read_json(iss, pt);
```

Now, let's find the address:

```
auto& addr = pt.get_child("data.user.addr").front().second;
```

This is an array containing a single element (which is also an array), let's get that:

```
auto& addrlines = addr.front().second;
```

This is an array with three address lines. Erase the last:

```
addrlines.erase(std::prev(addr.end()));
```

Print the result:

```
write_json(std::cout, pt);
```

### DEMO

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f931ed1caedbbe6)**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    std::istringstream iss(R"({"data": {
    "user": {
        "addr": [ [ 
            { "firstline": "123", "secondline": "LA" },
            { "firstline": "643", "secondline": "NY" },
            { "firstline": " ", "secondline": "VA" }
        ] ]
    }
}})");

    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    read_json(iss, pt);

    auto& addr = pt.get_child("data.user.addr").front().second;
    auto& addrlines = addr.front().second;

    addrlines.erase(std::prev(addr.end()));

    write_json(std::cout, pt);
}
```

Prints

```
{
    "data": {
        "user": {
            "addr": [
                {
                    "": {
                        "firstline": "123",
                        "secondline": "LA"
                    },
                    "": {
                        "firstline": "643",
                        "secondline": "NY"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

### Alternatively

To remove all addresses where the first line is empty (after trimming whitespace):

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a34fd4a9055ac5f)**

```
auto& addr = pt.get_child("data.user.addr");
auto& addrlines = addr.front().second;

for (auto it = addrlines.begin(); it != addrlines.end();) {
    auto firstline = it->second.get_optional<std::string>("firstline").value_or("");
    trim(firstline);
    if (firstline.empty()) {
        it = addrlines.erase(it);
    } else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```